# Two Kendo grid in the same page with same read method

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have to display two kendo grids with the same structure but different data on the same page. Since it is the same grid with only the data being different I decided to put the grid in a partial view and re-use it.

This is how the grid looks. If you see both the grid call the same `read` method in the controller but with a different parameter.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KitchenSink.Models.ViewModel.ConsolidatedTopNViewModel>()
.Name(gridName)
.Columns(column =>
{
    // Columns
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Group(g => g.Add(m => m.GroupID))
.Read(read => read.Action("ConsolidatedTopNPartialPage_Read", "Visuals", new { year = ViewBag.year}))        )
.Events(e => e.DataBound("consolidatedTopNDataBound")
.ExcelExport("excelExport"))
)
```

And in the controller

```
public ActionResult ConsolidatedTopNPartialPage_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int year)
{
List<ConsolidatedTopNViewModel> consolidated = opportunityService.ConsolidatedTopN(year);
return Json(consolidated.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This set-up works fine except one of a grid doesn't load sometimes. I get an exception in the `Json` method such as

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.

The model `ConsolidatedTopNViewModel` is a simple ViewModel and doesn't have any primary key or required field associated with it to be taken as the key by default.

The model is

```
public class ConsolidatedTopNViewModel
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int GroupID { get; set; }

        public string Primary_Owner { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Initiative { get; set; }
        public string Description_Assumptions { get; set; }

        public decimal? OpportunityRunRate { get; set; }
        public decimal? OpportunityCumulative { get; set; }

        public decimal? ForecastRunRate { get; set; }
        public decimal? ForecastCumulative { get; set; }

        public decimal? RemainingRunRate { get; set; }
        public decimal? RemainingCumulative { get; set; }

        public ConsolidatedTopNViewModel()
        {
            GroupID = 2;
        }
    }
```

Stack trace

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource
>   resource)    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey
>   key, TValue value, Boolean add)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.ClassFactory.GetDynamicClass(IEnumerable`1
>   properties)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.GroupDescriptorExpressionBuilder.CreateProjectionNewExpression(IEnumerable`1
>   propertyValuesExpressions)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.GroupDescriptorExpressionBuilder.CreateProjectionInitExpression()
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.GroupDescriptorExpressionBuilder.CreateAggregateFunctionsProjectionMemberBinding()
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.QueryableAggregatesExpressionBuilder.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at
>   System.Dynamic.Utils.CollectionExtensions.ToReadOnly[T](IEnumerable`1
>   enumerable)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MemberInit(NewExpression
>   newExpression, IEnumerable`1 bindings)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.GroupDescriptorExpressionBuilder.CreateSelectBodyExpression()
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.GroupDescriptorExpressionBuilder.CreateSelectExpression()
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.GroupDescriptorExpressionBuilderBase.CreateQuery()
>   at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.Aggregate(IQueryable
>   source, IEnumerable`1 aggregateFunctions)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.CreateDataSourceResult[TModel,TResult](IQueryable
>   queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState,
>   Func`2 selector)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(IQueryable
>   queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(IQueryable
>   queryable, DataSourceRequest request)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(IEnumerable
>   enumerable, DataSourceRequest request)    at
>   KitchenSink.Controllers.VisualsController.ConsolidatedTopNPartialPage_Read(DataSourceRequest
>   request, Int32 year) in
>   p:\KitchenSink-test\KitchenSink\Controllers\VisualsController.cs:line
>   101    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

Comment: Can you provide contents of `ConsolidatedTopNViewModel` class? Your controller action looks fine, probably some properties in viewmodel class causing the problem.

Comment: Could you also provide us the complete stacktrace? As mentioned, the shown code looks fine.

Comment: Probably usage of `year` parameter in `new { year = ViewBag.year }` and action method causing this problem. Try renaming the parameter argument or underlying property.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried it doesn't work still.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that method, you can try some other workaround. See below:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("ConsolidatedTopNPartialPage_Read","Visuals").Data("filters")))
```

and in your javascript function:

```
var yr = @ViewBag.year;
function filters() 
{
 return {
         year : yr
         };
}
```

Comment: I tried it doesn't make any difference. I'm not sure as to why this might work.

Comment: my mistake. I updated my answer. can you try it again.